# Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseOperation'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Currently, I am facing this problem and I don't know what is it about:

```
SetUserData(user) {
const userRef: AngularFireList<any> = this.firebase.list(`users/${user.uid}`);
const userData: User = {
  uid: user.uid,
  email: user.email,
  displayName: user.displayName,
  photoURL: user.photoURL,
  emailVerified: user.emailVerified
}
return userRef.set(userData, {
  merge: true
})
}
```

And this is an error in console:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseOperation'.
> Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'DataSnapshot': child, exists, exportVal,
> forEach, and 8 more.

Comment: What is `User` in your code? Note that Firebase can only store JSON objects, not other JavaScript objects (for example those that contain functions).

Comment: I've imported this interface: export interface User {
   uid: string;
   email: string;
   displayName: string;
   photoURL: string;
   emailVerified: boolean;
}

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked for me. You could return a new object based on the old object.

Add the 'Object.assign()' to return a new object. [Mozilla - Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign()
```

Your code refactored

```
SetUserData(user) {
  const userRef: AngularFireList<any> = 
  this.firebase.list(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const userData: User = Object.assign({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified
  })
  return userRef.set(userData, {
    merge: true
  })
}
```

You could refactor using the deconstruct method, see below

```
// Don't forget to import this line
import firebase from "firebase/compat";

SetUserData({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL, emailVerified }: firebase.User) {
  const userRef: AngularFireList<any> = this.firebase.list(`users/${uid}`);
  const userData = Object.assign({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL, emailVerified })
  return userRef.set(userData, { merge: true })
}
```